# Add to existing total using increment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a small fundraiser portion of my site and I need to keep adding to the total amount on every transaction and how many sponsors I get.

I have my transaction set as a POST request.

```
Route::post('/fundraiser/checkout', 'FundController@fundCheckout')->name('fundraiser-checkout');
```

In my controller I'm doing the following to increment the `sponsors_received` and `funding_received`.

Note the below `$subscription->quantity` = the amount given. $45 * 100 = 4500 cents for stripe.

```
            $funds = DB::table('funds')->where('cin', $cin)
            ->increment('funding_received', $subscription->quantity)
            ->increment('sponsors_received');
```

Want to keep adding to `funding_received` total and `sponsors_received`.

This actually does add to my `funding received`, but fails on `sponsors_received` with an odd error.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Call to a member
>   function increment() on integer

If I remove the `funding_received` query everything works fine. (Can I not use `increment` twice in a query?)

```
            $funds = DB::table('funds')->where('cin', $cin)
            ->increment('sponsors_received');
```

**Is there another way I can add to `funding_received` other than using `increment`?**

Using Laravel 6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `increment` method from the Query Builder is basically a custom `update` call that handles the increment process. And because it is an update, it returns the same result as an `update` call, which is the number of updated entries. That's why you get the error:

> Call to a member function increment() on integer

So you can't chain the next `increment` statement because the first one returns a number (`integer`) instead of a Query Builder instance. You can however do something like this:

```
$query = DB::table('funds')->where('cin', $cin);

$query->increment('funding_received', $subscription->quantity)
$query->increment('sponsors_received');
```

This will create a base query with your given condition and run each increment individually.

Comment: Smart! This worked perfectly by separating them into individual queries. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. The return type of `public function increment()` is an `int` https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_increment, so chaining calls to `increment()` is not allowed.

> `int increment(string $column, float|int $amount = 1, array $extra = [])`
>   Increment a column's value by a given amount.
>   Parameters
>   string `$column`
>   float|int  `$amount`
>   array `$extra`
>   Return Value
>   `int`

A simple way to update this is using the `save()` method:

```
$funds = Funds::where('cin', $cin)->firstOrFail();

$funds->funding_received += $subscription->quantity;
$funds->sponsors_received++;

$funds->save();
```

Note: This assumes you have a model for your `funds` table.

Comment: This works great as well. Thank you for your time, explanation and help. Much appreciated. Since the question was about using `increment` I went with that answer though.

Comment: No problem! Should note this is best used for single records; Bogdan's is a little more robust in that it would handles updating multiple records efficiently (not sure if `cin` is unique or not, etc.) Happy to help though! And yeah, no worries, I would have gone with their answer too.